# Why didn't the firefighters go in from the roof?

Tags: plot-explanation, devil

In the 2010 film Devil, things end badly for repair technician Dwight as his carabiner breaks dropping him fatally onto the roof of the trapped elevator. The detective in charge of the situation then gets a firefighting team to cut through the walls which takes considerable time and effort.

Dwight's original plan seemed sound and its failure was due to a highly improbable equipment malfunction. Given the urgency of the situation, why didn't the  firefighters just try the same thing with their superior equipment and extra manpower to step in if anything went wrong?